# How does std::shared_ptr delete a polymorphic type with protected destructor?

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers

In the following example:

```
class Base {
    protected:
    ~Base() {
        cout << "B\n";
    }
};

class Derived : public Base {
    public:
    virtual ~Derived(){
        cout << "D\n";
    }
};


int main() {
    Base *myBase_raw = new Derived();
    delete myBase_raw;
    return 0;
}
```

you expect to get:

> error: ‘virtual Base::~Base()’ is protected within this context delete myBase_raw;

Which is fine and a useful tool for stopping people from deleting your objects. This is also the case with `std::unique_ptr`. But when you swap the raw pointer for a `std::shared_ptr`, it compiles correctly:

```
int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<Base> myBaseS(new Derived());
}
```

And seemingly runs deleting the object and calling the `Base` and `Derived` destructors ([Live example](https://ideone.com/68wH9J)). According to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr):

> The object is destroyed using delete-expression or a custom deleter that is supplied to shared_ptr during construction.

Since I provided no custom deleter it should call `delete`. How is the above possible?

Comment: You call `~Derived` directly

Comment: `shared_ptr` captures the real type and so is able to call the actual destructor and not the the base class one. I'm not sure about how this is expressed in terms of the standard but there is more information [here](https://feherenfekete.wordpress.com/2014/04/24/shared_ptr-polymorphic-magic-pitfall/#Ref).

Comment: @PaulRooney Right, you should add this as an answer.

Comment: Your original code would be undefined behaviour anyway, because `Base` does not have a virtual destructor

Comment: @M.M Not calling a destructor is not by itself UB

Comment: @PasserBy: But the original doesn't "not call a destructor", it deletes non-polymorphically via a type other than the object's dynamic type.  Which is explicitly forbidden.

Comment: @BenVoigt That makes sense, I'll check that.

Comment: @BenVoigt _"The invocation of a destructor is subject to the usual rules for member functions; that is, if the object is not of the destructor's class type and not of a class derived from the destructor's class type (including when the destructor is invoked via a null pointer value), the program has undefined behavior."_ I can find no other mention in [class.dtor]

Comment: @PasserBy: There is no destructor invocation here, only usage of operator delete.  Now, the compiler would transform the delete operator into a destructor call plus deallocation call, if it were legal... but here it is not legal.  See `[expr.delete]`  *if the static type of the object to be deleted is diﬀerent from its dynamic type, the static type shall be a base class of the dynamic type of the object to be deleted and the static type shall have a virtual destructor or the behavior is undeﬁned*

Comment: @PasserBy: Good find on the dupe, by the way

Comment: @M.M it would be UB if you could compile it, which you cant, because the destructor in Base is protected ...

Comment: @PasserBy Nice dupe find. That is some obscure question text ...